# Extract hours from time and add minutes converted to hours and extract minutes from time and find reminder (modulo)

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to extract hours from time and add minutes converted to hours as well as  extract minutes from time and find reminder (modulo) in Oracle SQL.
So far I check a couple of link and try to google it but I couldn't find any solution.
So far here is what I try to do

```
                     SELECT
                    CONCAT(
                        -- extract hours from time and add minutes converted to hours
                        (SUM(SUBSTR(m.Time, ':', 1)) + TRUNCATE((SUM(SUBSTR(m.Time, ':', -1)) / 60),0)),
                        ':', 
                        -- extract minutes from time and find reminder (modulo)
                        LPAD((SUM(SUBSTR(m.Time, ':', -1)) MOD 60), 2, 0)) hours,
                    CONCAT(CONCAT(u.Surname, ' '),u.Lastname) AS Username,                           
                    u.UserID AS UserId,
                    ut.Date_,
                    m.MomentID
                FROM
                    moments m
                LEFT JOIN
                    user_timesheets ut
                ON
                    ut.UserTimesheetsID = m.UserTimesheetsID
                LEFT JOIN
                    users u
                ON
                    ut.user_id = u.UserID
                WHERE
                EXTRACT (MONTH FROM TO_DATE(ut.Date_,'YYYY-MM-DD')) = '2020-01-21'
                  -- EXTRACT (MONTH FROM TO_DATE(ut.Date_)) = '2020-07-30'
                AND
                 EXTRACT (YEAR FROM TO_DATE(ut.Date_,'YYYY-MM-DD')) = '2020-01-21'
                  -- EXTRACT (YEAR FROM TO_DATE(ut.Date_)) = '2020-07-30'
                AND
                    ut.user_id = 1
                AND
                    (SELECT MAX(MomentID) FROM moments WHERE m.parent = m.MomentID) IS NULL
                AND
                    m.AtestStatus = 1
```

The problem here is that I get error when I runt this query

```
The identifier name started with an ASCII character other than a
           letter or a number. After the first character of the identifier
           name, ASCII characters are allowed including "$", "#" and "_".
           Identifiers enclosed in double quotation marks may contain any
           character other than a double quotation. Alternate quotation
           marks (q'#...#') cannot use spaces, tabs, or carriage returns as
           delimiters. For all other contexts, consult the SQL Language
           Reference Manual.
*Action:   Check the Oracle identifier naming convention. If you are
           attempting to provide a password in the IDENTIFIED BY clause of
           a CREATE USER or ALTER USER statement, then it is recommended to
           always enclose the password in double quotation marks because
           characters other than the double quotation are then allowed.
```

I am sorry if this question look stupid for you but I am totally begginer in PL/SQL and I just looking for help.
Cheers :)

**Update**

Since I change % to `MOD` now I get error

```
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 7 Column: 64
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
LPAD((SUM(SUBSTR(m.Time, ':', -1)) % 60), 2, 0)
                                   -
                                   this!
```

Title says that you need to use *modulo*; if that's so, Oracle function name is `MOD`. See [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/MOD.html#GUID-E12A3928-2C50-45B0-B8C3-82432C751B8C).

Comment: Yes, I get this point. I found this solution in forum but it's like that is MySQL function not Oracle SQL

Comment: Well, some functions share the same name (not necessarily the same behavior and/or arguments) in different databases, but this one isn't among them.

Comment: I change this part but still I have error